# openSSH login slow for one user but not others

Tags: ssh, login, openssh

I'm running a server at home with Ubuntu 14.04. I have two users on the machine, say `user1` and `user2`, each able to ssh into the box. While `user1` logs in very quickly, `user2` takes about 20 seconds to log in. The same behavior happens regardless of which user is logging in from any particular machine.

Logging in as `user2` with `ssh -v` shows that the main pause happens after this message:

```
debug1: Sending environment.
```

The `.bashrc` files for the two users are identical. (A `diff` on them produces no output.) Same for the `.profile` files for `user1` and `user2`.

On the server, there is a line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with `AllowUsers user1 user2`. That same file has `UseDNS no` in it already. (I only mention that because most pages I found while searching for a solution mentioned to add that line.)

This issue started only about a week ago; I've had no such issues for the previous couple of years that I've been running the machine.

On a whim, I created a new user, `user3`, gave that user ssh access by editing `sshd_config` appropriately, and log in for the new user is fast. So it really seems to be something about the way `user2` is configured. But what?

Where should I look to find the root cause of the delay for the log in for `user2`?

EDIT: Below are the results from `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` when `user2` logs in:

```
Jun 21 11:27:10 topo sshd[18386]: Connection from re.mo.te.ip port XXXXX on se.rv.er.ip port XX
Jun 21 11:27:21 topo sshd[18386]: Accepted password for user2 from re.mo.te.ip port XXXXX ssh2
Jun 21 11:27:21 topo sshd[18386]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user2 by (uid=0)
Jun 21 11:27:21 topo systemd-logind[3347]: New session 25 of user user2.
Jun 21 11:28:03 topo sshd[18386]: User child is on pid XXXXX
Jun 21 11:28:03 topo sshd[18455]: Starting session: shell on pts/6 for user2 from re.mo.te.ip port XXXXX
```

Note the time stamps. The delay occurs after the last message here. No messages appear in auth.log once `user2` is finally logged in.

EDIT: Below are some results from `strace -f -p <sshd pid> -o out.tx -tt` where there are delays.

```
22733 12:59:10.414388 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/compat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
22733 12:59:10.840303 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/compat.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
22733 12:59:11.264716 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/compatmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
22733 12:59:11.717471 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/compat.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
22733 12:59:12.660275 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=11146, ...}) = 0
...
22733 12:59:12.661502 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/__future__.x86_64-linux-gnu.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
22733 12:59:13.212844 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/__future__.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
22733 12:59:14.441963 open("/usr/bin/dis.py", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
22733 12:59:14.900322 open("/usr/bin/dis.pyc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
22733 12:59:15.401750 stat("/usr/lib/python2.7/dis", 0x7ffcb599ddd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
22733 12:59:17.315288 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/termios.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
22733 12:59:17.967173 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/termiosmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
22733 12:59:18.511526 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/termios.py", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
22733 12:59:25.993287 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/monitor/time.x86_64-linux-gnu.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
22733 12:59:26.612018 open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/monitor/time.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
22733 12:59:29.688166 open("/proc/37/stat", O_RDONLY) = 9
22733 12:59:30.239695 fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
...
22733 12:59:30.240450 open("/proc/uptime", O_RDONLY) = 10
22733 12:59:31.634404 fstat(10, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
...
22733 12:59:34.287758 open("/proc/557/stat", O_RDONLY) = 9
22733 12:59:34.851662 fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
...
22758 12:59:39.500397 open(".", O_RDONLY) = 3
22758 12:59:40.377193 fchdir(3)         = 0
22758 12:59:40.377312 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/apt//lists/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
22758 12:59:40.377378 open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 4
22758 12:59:40.878676 fchdir(4)         = 0
...
22759 12:59:41.680427 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
22759 12:59:42.249796 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P \2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
...
22759 12:59:46.019309 open("/etc/lsb-release", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 64
22759 12:59:46.948115 fstat(64, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=105, ...}) = 0
...
22786 12:59:50.251281 open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
22786 12:59:50.970074 fcntl(1, F_GETFD) = 0
...
22785 12:59:53.338632 select(10, [3 4 6], [], NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [3])
22785 12:59:53.771002 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
```

A lot of this seems related to python libraries. However, they are also loaded when `user1` logs in, just without these 0.5s pauses.

Comment: Try `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` on the server while ssh`ing into the machine as `user2`. Maybe something useful is logged there?

Comment: Do you have a remote authentication server (radius or tacacs etc.) configured in you server?

Comment: @MartinvonWittich I edited to include that information.

Comment: What exactly is `bash` doing? E.g. compare output between users for `ssh -t host 'bash -xvl'` or so

Comment: instead of `-v` switch, user `-vvv` for a more detailed verbose output while logging in as user2. It looks like there is a 11 second delay before the password is accepted, compared to connection establishing. Check user2's `.ssh` directory permissions and the permissions for files inside `.ssh`. It might be trying to authenticate using a key pair first.

Comment: @thrig I did that for each user, and the results were the same for each. `diff` only showed that `user1` was replaced with `user2` in the outputs.

Comment: @coffeMug I have neither of those installed. I appear to be using xauth and libsasl.

Comment: @MelBurslan Did that. The password authentication is quick. The delay comes later, still after the same line above. Also did a `diff` on the results from this for `user1` and `user2` with no noticeable difference.

Comment: @MelBurslan The diff was this:

`< user1@host's password: 
< debug3: packet_send2: adding XX (len XX padlen XX extra_pad 64)
---
> user2@host's password: 
> debug3: packet_send2: adding XX (len XX padlen XX extra_pad 64)`

Comment: did you consider deleting user2 without deleting its home directory and recreating it ? I can't tell you what is happening in your case but user2 id might have an issue, cached somewhere, causing you this delay. It is a hard to diagnose issue.

Comment: @MelBurslan I have considered that. Since the newly created `user3` has none of these issues, I expect it would work. But, I want to know what's happening!

Comment: @BillKronholm try to run `strace -f -p <sshd pid>` on the server while logging in as `user2`.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich OK, that was interesting. The results from `strace` pause quite a bit during log in for `user2` but do not pause for `user1`. I saved the results from strace for each, and there are thousands of lines of output, but roughly the same number of lines for each. Is there something I should be looking for there in particular?

Comment: @BillKronholm can you figure out how it's pausing? Is it hanging during a single system call, or is it doing something in a loop? Maybe post an excerpt of the strace output of the part where it's hanging. The `strace` options `-o output.log -tt` to make it log to a file and prefix everything with timestamps could be helpful. There are additional timing options available that you could play around with, see `man strace`.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich I updated the question with results from the `strace` where there were significant pauses. Most are related to python. These same messages appear when `user1` logs in, just without the pauses.

Comment: Do you run a script when logging users? Characteristics of system, security packages to be installed?

Comment: Maybe something PAM-related?

Comment: Hmm. the `strace` output doesn't seem to be very helpful. I don't think that these syscalls really take that long (for example the 400ms delay between the 2nd and 3rd `open`); most probably `sshd` is wasting time in a different way without actually doing syscalls. You could try `ltrace` next ^^

Comment: @MartinvonWittich With `ltrace` running, I get `Couldn't find .dynsym or .dynstr in "/proc/27881/exe"` regardless of which user is logging in. This also results in a broken pipe for the ssh connection logging in.